# Include html href code to shotcode with "show content on a date"

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to use a shortcode to show determinate content depending on a date given, I have this code on function.php on WP:

```
add_shortcode( 'stime', 'stime_f' );
function stime_f( $atts, $content = '' ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( [
                'type'   => false,
    ], $atts );
    $output = '';
   if ( $a['type'] ) {
    $a['type'] = array_map( 'trim', str_getcsv( $a['type'], ',' ) );
    }


            foreach ($a as $value){
        $list0 = $value[0];
        $list1 = $value[1];
    }
    
    $tm = strtotime($list1);
    if ( time() < $tm ) {
    $list = "SOON";
    return $list;
}   
    $list = $list0;
    return $list;
}
```

So I used when publish:

```
[stime type="http://site1.com
http://site2.com,2020-12-05"]
```

And works, when it's not the date give result: `SOON`
otherwise result:

```
 http://site1.com
 http://site2.com
```

Results are fine, but I want to use:

```
[stime type="<a href="site1.com" target="_blank">SITE1</a>
<a href="https://site2.com" target="_blank">SITE2</a>,2020-12-05"]
```

I suppose it's for quotes on href and target, there are some way to make it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use enclosing shortcodes for this.

Below is the updated code:

```
add_shortcode( 'stime', 'stime_f' );
function stime_f( $atts, $content ) {
    if ( $content ) {
        $a = array_map( 'trim', str_getcsv( $content, ',' ) );
        $list0 = $a[0];
        $list1 = $a[1];

        $tm = strtotime($list1);
        if ( time() < $tm ) {
            $list = "SOON";
            return $list;
        }   
        $list = $list0;
        return $list;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Then use shortcode like this:

```
[stime] <a href="site1.com" target="_blank">SITE1</a>
<a href="https://site2.com" target="_blank">SITE2</a>,2020-12-05 [/stime]
```

Comment: or you can also add date in shortcode attribute and markup in between the shortcode tags